# Sample size for a logistic regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, experiment-design, sample-size

I would like to calculate the minimal number of participants (sample size) I need for my experimental protocol. I use logistic regression. I compare two groups in a protocol having three independent variables (each one having two modalities) and one dependent binary variable.

For each experimental condition (e.g., group 1, modality 1 of independent variable 1, modality 1 of independent variable 2, modality 1 of independent variable 3), participants are tested in 9 items (each item is an observation, I guess).

It is worth noticing that the probability of having a 1 (success) is much higher than having 0 in both groups but, according to my hypothesis, I should have more 0s in a group than in the other (even though less 0s than 1s in both).

I know that I need at least 10 observations for each factor when I use a logistic regression, but on the one hand I am not sure what an observation is (number of participants, number of items, or number of participants*number of items, etc.). On the other hand, I don't know if the highest probability of having 1 over 0 influences this estimation, since the logistic regression works better with around 50/50 distribution of zeros (which I most likely won't have as I said previously).

Do you have any idea of the amount of participants I need for condition and/or how am I supposed to estimate it?

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what you mean when you say you have "one dependent binary variable" in the first paragraph, but then say "participants are tested in 9 items" in the second paragraph. Are you doing 9 separate logistic regressions, one for each "item," are you using the sum/proportion of 1 values among the 9 items as the outcome, or something else? Are you evaluating interactions among the independent variables, and if so, which ones? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Also, when you edit the question, please say more about the specific hypothesis you want to test. It seems to be related to differences between Group 1 and Group 2, but are you just interested in whether there are any differences between the groups or in specific differences with respect to outcomes associated with particular independent variables/combinations?